# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader

Tags: maven, tomcat7, pom.xml, spring-3, xml-configuration

I am working on a Spring application on Tomcat7, JDK1.7, Maven and other components. Recently, I made a major change to the application, requiring switching over to Spring 3. After the change, I'm seeing the below exception on deploying to dev server. The application runs flawlessly on my local system though.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet amadeusAce threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/amadeusAce-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:375)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:311)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:258)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:229)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:115)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.configureScanner(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:100)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:83)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:311)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:258)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:229)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:115)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I don't think there's any issue with the said xml `amadeusAce-servlet.xml` as well because there there is no change in the file since last deployment.

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ace.amadeus</groupId>
    <artifactId>AmadeusSpring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Simple CXF project using spring configuration</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Java.net</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/java.net2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ibatis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
            <version>0.8a</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.183949</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.726</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sax</groupId>
            <artifactId>sax</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Anything you can see from the above resources?? I'd absolutely love to hear from you.
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the below post, I found out the classpath from where dependencies are resolved. Results below:

```
file:/D:/ace-amadeus-ws/AmadeusSpring/target/classes/
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.2/httpclient-4.2.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.2/httpcore-4.2.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/0.2/jsr311-api-0.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.8/jersey-server-1.8.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/2.1.3/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec/1.0/geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec/1.0.2/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/asm/asm/2.2.3/asm-2.2.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-api/2.1.3/cxf-api-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-common-utilities/2.1.3/cxf-common-utilities-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec/1.0.1/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.2/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2/xml-resolver-1.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.2/XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.6/wstx-asl-3.2.6.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/neethi/neethi/2.0.4/neethi-2.0.4.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-common-schemas/2.1.3/cxf-common-schemas-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-core/2.1.3/cxf-rt-core-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.7/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec/1.3/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.2/FastInfoset-1.2.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/2.1.3/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-common/2.1.3/cxf-tools-common-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.1.7/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec/1.1.2/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/2.1.3/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.1/jaxb-api-2.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-xml/2.1.3/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/2.1.3/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-addr/2.1.3/cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/javax/xml/soap/saaj-api/1.3/saaj-api-1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.2/saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/2.1.3/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-ibatis/2.0.8/spring-ibatis-2.0.8.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/2.0.8/spring-jdbc-2.0.8.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springmodules/spring-modules-validation/0.8a/spring-modules-validation-0.8a.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.2/commons-lang-2.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.3.0/commons-validator-1.3.0.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.7/commons-digester-1.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring/2.0.3/spring-2.0.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/rhino/js/1.6R2/js-1.6R2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/tiles/tiles-jsp/2.0.7/tiles-jsp-2.0.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/tiles/tiles-core/2.0.7/tiles-core-2.0.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/tiles/tiles-api/2.0.7/tiles-api-2.0.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.4/servlet-api-2.4.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.1.2/jstl-1.1.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/standard-1.1.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/20030825.184428/commons-dbcp-20030825.184428.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/20030825.183949/commons-pool-20030825.183949.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/apache/ibatis/ibatis-sqlmap/2.3.4.726/ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/uk/com/robust-it/cloning/1.8.2/cloning-1.8.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/sax/sax/2.0.1/sax-2.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` occur if there is some issue with the jar loaded. I think that on the system that you are trying to run this code on, has **CLASSPATH** set to some path which is `loading the older version of the jar`. Use the following code to find out the paths from where the ClassLoader is resolving the dependencies

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)Main.class.getClassLoader();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
    }
```

Put this method in Main class and execute it in the system that is giving this error. It will show you all the paths from where the dependencies have been resolved. Find out if any of the paths have older version of the jar.

Hope this helps your cause.

Comment: On my local machine, it displays a list of jars as expected. On dev, it just displays the current path: [file:/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Jenkins3/src/main/java/com/ace/amadeus/] :o

Comment: I have added the list of classpath as an edit. I'm dubious about file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring/2.0.3/spring-2.0.3.jar. I'll add an exclusion for this in pom.xml and check. In the meantime, if you see anything, please let me know. Thank you! :)

Comment: seems that should be the problem. Did you try the above thing?

Comment: No idea where to exclude it, in which of the depencencies :o

Comment: can you not go to that location in the file system where the jar is placed?

Comment: [Excluding dependencies in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) this could help. I myself have not used maven so cannot comment more on that, but I think that older version of spring jar is causing problems

Comment: Oh, i mean exclusion of spring 2.0.3 since I have nowhere added spring version 2.03 in my pom. I will try this out today. I think there's some other dependency that requires this version of spring, and that coexistence of two spring versions is giving the problem. I'm almost convinced that occurrence of multiple spring versions is the main problem, but let's just make sure first.

Comment: It infact was because of the spring-2.0.3 dependency. I added an exclusion in pom: 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
   <version>0.8a</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>, then performed mvn clean, mvn eclipse:eclipse and mvn package again, and it was gone.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, getting the below exception while trying to run my job through MyEclipse IDE.
*Caused by: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Enviroment;*

After removing the default Spring2 jars from Java Build path, it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Problem was **org.apache.cxf's** version defined as 2.2.3.Because of that even **org.springframework's** version defined as 4.0.0.RELEASE maven downloaded org.springframework's 2.x version.Because of this I got the same error.After changing the org.apache.cxf version to **2.7.x** and removing all sping2.x from.m2 error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the error for me was to add in each spring xml in my project the version of the spring-beans. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

    <!-- spring stuff here -->
</beans>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- spring stuff here -->
</beans>
```