# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment; With zkoss

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, zk

I am facing following error,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:81)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know from google search that its related to dependency issue. So here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>TempApp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.zbc.tempapp</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TempApp</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK CE</id>
            <name>ZK CE Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <jpa.version>1.0.1.Final</jpa.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.commons.annotation.version>4.0.4.Final</hibernate.commons.annotation.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <springVersion>4.1.2.RELEASE</springVersion>
        <log4j2Version>2.0</log4j2Version>
        <springDataJpaVersion>1.4.3.RELEASE</springDataJpaVersion>
        <apacheCommonsLangVersion>3.2.1</apacheCommonsLangVersion>
        <apacheCommonsCollection>4.0</apacheCommonsCollection>
        <apacheCommonsEmail>1.3.2</apacheCommonsEmail>
        <quartzVersion>2.2.1</quartzVersion>
        <zkVersion>7.0.3</zkVersion>
        <zkSpringVersion>3.1.1</zkSpringVersion>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <plugin.maven.war>2.4</plugin.maven.war>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <plugin.maven.compiler>3.0</plugin.maven.compiler>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- asyn logger log4j 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- hibernate/jpa related -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.commons.annotation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springDataJpaVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- quartz schedular -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartzVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Zkoss Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>${zkVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
            <version>${zkVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>${zkVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
            <version>${zkVersion}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkspring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> -->

    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkspring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkspring-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Apache commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheCommonsEmail}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheCommonsLangVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheCommonsCollection}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.maven.war}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true
                                </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true
                                </addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Implementation-Build>${BUILD_TAG}</Implementation-Build>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.maven.compiler}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <optimize>true</optimize>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- make it false to execute test cases -->
                                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- make it false to execute test cases -->
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642947/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-factory-xml-xmlreadercont. Do you have same jar with different versions?

Comment: No, I tried removing the zkoss dependency but its no help, no I don't think so I have explicity mentioned 2 different versions. Would the presence of another version in .m2 directory count??

Comment: I also deleted the folders under .m2 and tried building and deploying, still the same error.

Comment: One thing I notice is that you are using Spring 4.1.2 and an old version of Spring Data JPA which could lead to including different spring versions. Also make sure that the zk spring integration supports Spring 4.1. Do a `mvn dependency:tree` to see which dependencies are actually used.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem as you. Two hours finding was going wrong... After found your question and saw that probably it's a dependency problem.

It is, I solved this issue just adding spring beans dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

This was for me a dependency compatibility problem between the spring jars and spring data.

The versions before the error (no errors) :

```
<spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springdata.version>1.6.1.RELEASE</springdata.version>
```

After updating spring data to 1.10.2.RELEASE the error appends, resolved by upgrading spring version to 4.3.2.RELEASE :

```
<spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springdata.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</springdata.version>
```

To ensure you use the correct spring version you can skip the maven declaration of the spring dependencies and keep only the spring data dependency.
Or you can check in the maven repository which spring version is used by your spring data version and update consequentely.

Comment: Switching my spring version to 4.3.2.RELEASE fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This error is pretty clear,
The class

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext
```

does not contain the method getEnvironment (java method notation)

```
.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment
```

If you look at the **Spring bean** library that is included in you application, and run a javap -l on the class, you will probably notice that this method **really** does not exist...

```
**javap.exe c:\XmlReaderContext.class** -l
Compiled from "XmlReaderContext.java"
public class org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext extends org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext {
  public org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext(org.springframework.core.io.Resource, org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ProblemReporter, org.springframework.beans.factory.par
aderEventListener, org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.SourceExtractor, org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader, org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerRes

  public final org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader getReader();
  public final org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry getRegistry();
  public final org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader getResourceLoader();
  public final java.lang.ClassLoader getBeanClassLoader();
  public final org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerResolver getNamespaceHandlerResolver();
  public java.lang.String generateBeanName(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition);
  public java.lang.String registerWithGeneratedName(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition);
  public org.w3c.dom.Document readDocumentFromString(java.lang.String);
}
```

Just upgrade to a later version that contains the method for this **Spring bean** dependency > 4.3.2

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
if using spring 3.17 
use 
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>1.6.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

If this error is thrown at server during starting/deploying web application, then

1. Find jar which contains mentioned class in your project org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext
2. Try find the same jar at the server in common lib folder.
3. Set the same version of jar or put provided scope in pom.xml file