# How to solve the noSuchMethodError when call a method which contains a Spring ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There are two project I have build( more than two indeed),the 1st one is DataCollector which do data service built with Spring and Hibernate, the 2nd is CoreProcessor which do analysis to these data built with Drools. The CoreProcessor need call some methods supported by DataCollector to return data for itself, these methods will first find application context .xml file, and then create session and do queries.When I test there method in DataCollector project, they are run smoothly, However it returns Error when CoreProcessor project calls them.
Here is the Error Message:

```
21:14:57.332 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
21:14:57.336 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
21:14:57.336 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
21:14:57.340 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6108b2d7: startup date [Mon Apr 11 21:14:57 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
21:14:57.378 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
21:14:57.379 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
21:14:57.379 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
21:14:57.390 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ConnectToLocalDataBase.xml]
21:14:57.402 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
21:14:57.422 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
21:14:57.428 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd=/org/springframework/ws/config/web-services-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd=/org/springframework/ws/config/web-services-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-1.5.xsd=/org/springframework/ws/config/web-services-1.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.0.xsd}
21:14:57.429 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
21:14:57.466 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd
21:14:59.078 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions
21:14:59.090 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.x.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver - Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services=org.springframework.ws.config.WebServicesNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc=org.springframework.jdbc.config.JdbcNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm=org.springframework.oxm.config.OxmNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler}
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [ConnectToLocalDataBase.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at Testcase.TestDataSource.getTestBill(TestDataSource.java:20)
at testCases.DataRequestTest.main(DataRequestTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:81)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1426)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
... 15 more
```

Comment: please share configuration file. Instead of "session blabla" you could specify  more about what your doing.

Comment: I found it, thank you. I'll be careful next time

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. It mentions the same error. You need to add an extra dependency

[NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment; With zkoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607961/nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-factory-xml-xmlreadercontext-getenv)

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: fixed!..._(:з」∠)_  Both projects should add dependencies. thanks!

Comment: yes ,thank you very much. After I add some dependencies it fixed!